# Sharepoint 2013 on Windows 7

Tags: installation

Is impossible to install SP2013 on windows 7 Client?

In SP2010 there was a "excamotage" with the config.xml modified ...

Is it possible also for this new version!?

Answer (score 4):

No it isn't possible to deploy a SharePoint 2013 on Windows 7. You should install Microsoft Server 2008 or higher.

Look at this link:

http://www.shailwx.com/2012/07/sharepoint-2013-development-image-part-1-creating-a-virtual-machine/

Comment: Thank you, but i know this solution ... I haven't enough HW resources to install Windows Server on my machine, and our Server doesn't allow more than one remote session ... how could I develop web parts with visual studio on my remote machine?

Comment: You Should instal the tlial MS 2008 or higger to Virtual Machine like virtualbox.

Comment: You have Here all whaty You should do: http://www.shailwx.com/2012/07/sharepoint-2013-development-image-part-1-creating-a-virtual-machine/

Comment: If your machine doesn't have the resources to run Windows Server you definitely will not be able to run a SharePoint 2013 virtual machine locally. You basically have three options: 1) Get an Office 365 Development site (which is free but you will only be able to build Apps), or 2) Have your network admin create a development (virtual) machine that you can RDP into, or 3) Use a cloud hosting service like CloudShare

Answer (score 0):

Now you can install on windows 7/8, you decide if it's a good fit for you. Of course ABSOLUTELY COMPLETELY unsupported but IMHO it works great for a dev environment.

http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inl%C3%A4gg/6/Install-SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-7-8-8-1

Comment: Please add the main steps for doing it to your post. The purpose of this site is not to drive traffic to your private blog, but to actually help people that has a problem solve them